# document.cookie is empty, however there are some cookies on this site

Tags: javascript, cookies

document.cookie is empty, however there are some cookies on this site

I try to clean cookie from http://ya.ru (firebug show some cookies on this site) but document.cookie is empty

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookies being set on `ya.ru` are invalid.  From the headers:

> Set-Cookie:S=; path=/; expires=Thu, 12-Apr-2001 18:01:31 GMT
>   S=; domain=.ya.ru; path=/; expires=Thu, 12-Apr-2001 18:01:31 GMT

That means that the cookie `S` is being set to blank (and once on a potentially invalid domain `.ya.ru`)

and from `kiss.ya.ru`:

> Cookie:yandexuid=740707471300761151; fuid01=4d880a3f046a3adb.XAGDFwCcblJ88BiI0-dizIwYqqeFGNCvuzmuswZQjSzBOiQsoOPEvCh0rUsbgtkecV63gqRK6ya5qdTjR-LlwdBAsop6Em9vXP6vlBLZgLZQolx7uVPD4Qw_PPWCapoE
>   yandexuid=740707471300761151; fuid01=4d880a3f046a3adb.XAGDFwCcblJ88BiI0-dizIwYqqeFGNCvuzmuswZQjSzBOiQsoOPEvCh0rUsbgtkecV63gqRK6ya5qdTjR-LlwdBAsop6Em9vXP6vlBLZgLZQolx7uVPD4Qw_PPWCapoE

Since the site is running on `ya.ru`, you can't read the `kiss.ya.ru` cookies due to security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a security thing.  If the Javascript has been load from a host or path different than the one set for the cookie, the cookie's invisible.

Comment: According to firebug it has 3 cookies from ya.ru, kiks.ya.ru, suggest.ya.ru. I've understand the security things, but first cookie(from ya.ru) must be show, mustn't it?